# React-Native error adding a video using Expo to the App.js for background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, simulator

This is the error message:

[image]

Error:
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string
(for
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
components)
but got: object.

```
Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at App.js:31)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at App.js:30)
```

I added a video with the Expo to my App.js and I am getting this error and can't seem to solve it. I am trying to set the background to a video that I have saved to my assets folder and desktop.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Video from 'expo';
import { MaterialIcons, Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        mute: false,
        fullScreen: false,
        shouldPlay: true,
    }

handlePlayAndPause = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        shouldPlay: !prevState.shouldPlay
    }));
}

handleVolume = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        mute: !prevState.mute,
    }));
}

 render() {
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}> React Native Video </Text>
                    <Video
                        source={{ uri: './assets/background.mp4' }}
                        shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
                        resizeMode="cover"
                        style={{ width, height: 300 }}
                        isMuted={this.state.mute}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.controlBar}>
                        <MaterialIcons 
                            name={this.state.mute ? "volume-mute" : "volume-up"}
                            size={45} 
                            color="white" 
                            onPress={this.handleVolume} 
                        />
                        <MaterialIcons 
                            name={this.state.shouldPlay ? "pause" : "play-arrow"} 
                            size={45} 
                            color="white" 
                            onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause} 
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
  </View>
          );
      }
       }



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    controlBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
        height: 45,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
    }
    });

package.json
    {
      "name": "empty-project-template",
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
      "start": "expo start",
      "android": "expo start --android",
      "ios": "expo start --ios",
      "postinstall": "react-native link",
      "eject": "expo eject"
    },
      "dependencies": {
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
      "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
      "expo": "^30.0.1",
      "link": "^0.1.5",
      "react": "16.3.1",
      "react-native": "^0.55.0",
      "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
      "react-native-video": "^3.2.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a video thats in a directory in your project you have to `require` it in the source property

```html
<Video
  source={require('./assets/background.mp4')}
  shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
  resizeMode="cover"
  style={{ width, height: 300 }}
  isMuted={this.state.mute}
/>
```

Here is the documentation for using the Video component https://github.com/expo/expo-docs/blob/master/versions/v25.0.0/sdk/video.md

Also you should be importing video like this
`import {Video} from 'expo'`

Comment: wow those 2 things worked! especially missing the brackets for the video. Thank you so much! i was using react-native video and had to totally change it up due to expo.